# Get FilterPart of FilterDefinition in SSJS (ExactTarget)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I'm trying to fetch the FilterParts of FilterDefinitions in SSJS (for debugging now used on a landing page).

```
var results = FilterDefinition.Retrieve({Property:"CategoryID",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:"xxxx"});
```

As expected, this gives me an array of FilterDefinitions from a specific folder, and I see most of the properties just fine. I cannot read the `DataFilter` property though, it just gives the object type when I Stringify it:

`"DataFilter":"ExactTarget.Integration.WSDL.ComplexFilterPart"`

How can I access the actual `FilterPart` so I can see what the filter is constructed of?

Comment: Seems that the only way is to request the `DataFilter` using Marketing Cloud API (like an external sys) because in my experience none of the build in methods of Ampscript and SSJS return you something differente from: `ExactTarget.Integration.WSDL.ComplexFilterPart` or `null` (with WSproxy).

Comment: Yes, but there are some undocumented hints in WSProxy for dealing with those data types, e.g. __Type__.  Curious if someone knows how to cast/convert those in a retrieve.

Comment: not saying it can't be done, but maybe to help others' research: 1) docs say, filterDefinition doesn't support retrieve (or has limits at least) - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/supported_operations_for_objects_and_methods.html?q=methods+and+objects ; 2) adam surfaced information around it, like the aforementioned " _ _ type __ " - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/260225/create-filter-definition-via-wsproxy - this person has examples for all methods: https://sfmc-curated.com/sfmc-stack/Work-with-Data-Filters-in-SSJS-using-WSProxy?id=4288